# Spring Boot 1.5.1 and "The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

A couple of weeks ago, I upgraded the version of Spring from to 1.4.x.RELEASE to 1.5.1.RELEASE.

Suddenly it has become a fight to start my Spring Boot service due this error:

"The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle"

Same code, different version

It's quite funny, since on my local env (OSX) the same code is usually starting fine, but on Heroku is failing randomly on different deploys (looks like a different order on classpath Class resolution, due OS or due different JDK implementations)

I have even refactored the code to use field injection instead of constructor one everywhere without success.

Any suggestion? why this Spring version has suddenly started to produce these errors?

Thanks!

Comment: Most likely, you didn't upgrade all of the components, just some of them. (And note that 1.5 is the *Spring Boot* version, not Spring.)

Comment: @mre, well there is not a code base: is just general to all the application, indeed I am unable to reproduce locally (osx + JDK vs Heroku + OpenJDK I guess)

Comment: @chrylis I did: is quite random. All components are now on Spring Boot 1.5.x, and if you mean if all are now field injection based, they are. Is like chasing ghosts: the problem just move.

Comment: Can you provide the logs?

Comment: @mre I'm not the OP.

Answer (score 4):

Find out which bean(s) is the reason for cycle from logs and use @Lazy annotation with @Autowired for this bean(s) in your code. For most cases this should do the trick.

Comment: Hi Ahmad. Actually I suggest to use "Lazy" annotation for cycled beans. This is an answer. But "Lazy" annotation is not always a solution for cycled dependencies. Because of that I asked for more information. Thank you for your concerns.

Comment: @barbakini Fair point, it would probably be better to edit to rephrase though.

Comment: Hi, I edited it to just include my suggestion to problem. Thanks for the comment